# Salesforce Campaign sync with Marketo in reverse

Tags: campaign, sync, marketo

My company would like to create campaigns in Salesforce and export them to Marketo. As far as I know, it is only possible to do this in reverse (create Marketo campaigns and export to Salesforce).

I know that this is not possible using Marketo's API. But could there be some other way to do this?

Comment: have you tried Marketo customer support and/or forums?

Comment: they told me that it's not possible. I'm looking for a possible workaround